# Sqlite database restrictions in windows store apps

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have some issues with Sq lite. I read a [Microsoft article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-c16aea77#content)

In that site it is mentioning as "**When you create a new C# or VB Windows Store project in Visual Studio, it supports all architectures (x86, x64 and ARM) by default. But since you added Sq Lite to the project, you can’t build one package that targets all architectures. You have to build one target for each. Select Build|Configuration Manager and select x86, x64 or ARM from the Platform drop-down list.**"

My application is Newspaper app developed using C# for windows tablet. Can i build for all processors.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, the only downside is that you must compile three different times your app, to support the ARM, X86 and X&4 architectures.

This can done easily if you configure your configuration manager with the different architectures ;)

Check this link on [How to: Create and Edit Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any any other Data Storage methods to store data rather than SQlite

Comment: For me i cant change my configuration manager dynamically,i.e., the user may use any type of platform (ARM, X86, X64). Is there any code change platform dependent on Customer requirement. 


please help me
Thank you in advance..

Comment: When you publish your app, you will submit 3 different packages and microsoft will handle them and distribute the correct one when a user downloads your app ;). So if the user A has a Surface RT when we tries to download the app the Microsoft will give him the ARM version, if it has a x64 desktop, MS will give him the x64 package, and for x86 the same thing ;)